# No VNC extension on display on VNC desktop

Tags: vnc

I have started `vncserver` or remote instance with the `vncserver` command, and now am able to connect to it with VNC client.

Unfortunately, I can't start `vncconfig` due to error

```
No VNC extension on display
```

Everything is happening on VNC. How can it be?

[image]

Comment: You should type `tightvncserver` on the remote OS.  `vncserver` is userd for RealVNC.

Comment: Replace your VNC with the TigerVNC server and remove other vnc packages.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a copy of vncserver

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/vncserver /usr/bin/vncserver.bkp
```

2) Open vncserver and find `$defaultXStartup`

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/vncserver
```

3) Modify lines to:

```
$defaultXStartup
    = ("#!/bin/sh\n\n".
       "# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:\n".
       "# unset SESSION_MANAGER\n".
       "# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc\n\n".
       "[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup\n".
       "[ -r \$HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb \$HOME/.Xresources\n".
       "xsetroot -solid grey\n".
       "vncconfig -iconic &\n".
       "x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title \"\$VNCDESKTOP Desktop\" &\n".
       "x-window-manager &\n");
```

This will ensure that you have all the right things started inside VNC.

In case you face issues, please follow the below link and ensure you have all the stuff is rightly installed.

See [Installation of VNC server on Ubuntu](https://hackernoon.com/installation-of-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-1cf035370bd3).